# Determine string is even length with regular expression

Tags: formal-languages, regular-expressions

There is a set of strings of even length over $\{k,l,m\}$ that contain exactly one $k$. And I try to write its regular expression.

I think it can be in that format:

```
   ODD PREFIX k EVEN SUFFIX | EVEN PREFIX k ODD SUFFIX
```

Is this idea true? If it is true, it looks too long, is there any shorter way to write it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your answer shows that you have understood the question, you need to be more precise. In particular, the prefix and the suffix should be words on the alphabet $A = \{l, m\}$. Then, step by step, one has:

1. The set of words of even length on the alphabet $A$ is $(AA)^*$.
2. The set of words of odd length on the alphabet $A$ is $(AA)^*A$.
3. According to your idea, which is right, your language is $(AA)^*k(AA)^*A \cup (AA)^*Ak(AA)^*$.

Comment: In my solution $(AA)^{*}$ represent $(lm \cup ll \cup mm \cup ml)^{*}$ and $A$ represent $(l \cup m)$. But I'm not sure from first one. I think there should be easy way to show $AA$ or $(AA)^{*}$

Comment: You can indeed write $A$ as $(l \cup m)$ and $(AA)^*$ as $(lm \cup ll \cup mm \cup ml)^*$.

Comment: Okey, thank you. I am very happy to do it corretcly :)

Comment: Actually, a slightly more algebraic notation helps for this type of computation. If you replace $\cup$ by $+$, then you get $A = (l+m)$ and then $AA = (l+m)(l+m)= (l+m)l + (l+m)m = ll +lm +ml +mm$.

Comment: Wow that is also very helpful for me. Thank you again